# Failed to execute maven-surefire-plugin but only with circleci

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, circleci

I have quite weird problem with surefire plugin because even though I've added surefire plugin to my spring boot projectwhen I try to run this robust project which happen to be composed of parent module and two other with help of intellij. then tests are passed and everything seem to be ok but when I try to run this project with circleci, it results with this error

```
[INFO] sfg-pet-clinic ..................................... SUCCESS [  0.578 s]
[INFO] pet-clinic-data .................................... FAILURE [  1.233 s]
[INFO] pet-clinic-web ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.038 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-11-12T20:13:34Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0:test (default-test) on project pet-clinic-data: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /home/circleci/repo/pet-clinic-data/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
[ERROR] The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was /bin/sh -c cd /home/circleci/repo/pet-clinic-data && /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -jar /home/circleci/repo/pet-clinic-data/target/surefire/surefirebooter4736163973627057032.jar /home/circleci/repo/pet-clinic-data/target/surefire 2018-11-12T20-13-33_883-jvmRun1 surefire7954723918855682468tmp surefire_01455652050680240151tmp
[ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was /bin/sh -c cd /home/circleci/repo/pet-clinic-data && /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -jar /home/circleci/repo/pet-clinic-data/target/surefire/surefirebooter4736163973627057032.jar /home/circleci/repo/pet-clinic-data/target/surefire 2018-11-12T20-13-33_883-jvmRun1 surefire7954723918855682468tmp surefire_01455652050680240151tmp
[ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:671)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:533)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:278)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:244)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1194)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1022)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:868)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

this is pom of  pet-clinic-data catalog:

<

```
parent>
        <artifactId>sfg-pet-clinic</artifactId>
        <groupId>guru.springframework</groupId>
        <version>0.0.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>pet-clinic-data</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

What is even weirder when I try another project with use of circleci then I've got preety the same error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20.1:test (default-test) on project spring5-recipe-app: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /home/circleci/repo/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
[ERROR] The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
```

but I think that adding another project pom with surefire with the same place is pointelss..

My config of circleci

```
# Java Maven CircleCI 2.0 configuration file
    #
    # Check https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/language-java/ for more details
    #
    version: 2
    jobs:
      build:
        docker:
          # specify the version you desire here
          - image: circleci/openjdk:8-jdk

          # Specify service dependencies here if necessary
          # CircleCI maintains a library of pre-built images
          # documented at https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/
          # - image: circleci/postgres:9.4

        working_directory: ~/repo

        environment:
          # Customize the JVM maximum heap limit
          MAVEN_OPTS: -Xmx3200m

        steps:
          - checkout

          # Download and cache dependencies
          - restore_cache:
              keys:
              - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "pom.xml" }}
              # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
              - v1-dependencies-

          - run: mvn install -DskipTests

          - run: mvn dependency:go-offline

          - save_cache:
              paths:
                - ~/.m2
              key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "pom.xml" }}

          # run tests!
          - run: mvn integration-test
```

corrected config.yml

```
# Java Maven CircleCI 2.0 configuration file
#
# Check https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/language-java/ for more details
#
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      # specify the version you desire here
      - image: circleci/openjdk:8-jdk

      # Specify service dependencies here if necessary
      # CircleCI maintains a library of pre-built images
      # documented at https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/
      # - image: circleci/postgres:9.4

    working_directory: ~/repo

    environment:
      # Customize the JVM maximum heap limit
      MAVEN_OPTS: -Xmx3200m

    steps:
      - checkout

      # Download and cache dependencies
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
          - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "pom.xml" }}
          # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
          - v1-dependencies-

      - run: mvn dependency:go-offline

      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ~/.m2
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "pom.xml" }}

      # run tests!
      - run: mvn integration-test
```

Comment: Correctly configure surefire plugin version at least 2.22.1 ...`maven-surefire-plugin:2.20.1:test (default-test) on project spring5-recipe-app: There are test failures.`...Apart from that you seemed to misunderstand the concept of the life cycle cause in your `circle` you are calling `install` and `integration-test` but `install` already includes running of the `integration-test`...furthermore integration test comprises of three life cycle step `pre-integration-test`, `integration-test` and `post-integration-test`....

Comment: I did what you said but it didn't help
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) on project spring5-recipe-app: There are test failures.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem may be due to this Debian bug: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=911925

I had the same problem and fixed it as follows.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot bro. It solves.
I did some reseatch and i found that it can be solved upgrading the project to JDK-11.

Comment: @wwww, please accept this answer as it solved my problem too.